# Getting every row count result when grouping by date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, calendar

I want to count rows in a table and group them by date. The data is going to be used for excel graphs later, so it would be easier if the result also included dates with the count equal to 0.

For example, executing

```
SELECT date, count(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY 1
```

gives me

```
...
2013-01-01 5
2013-01-03 35
2013-01-04 57
2013-01-05 51
2013-01-07 50
2013-01-09 15
...
```

What I want the result to be is

```
...
2013-01-01 5
2013-01-02 0
2013-01-03 35
2013-01-04 57
2013-01-05 51
2013-01-06 0
2013-01-07 50
2013-01-08 0
2013-01-09 15
...
```

Is there a way to get such results without having to create a table with all the dates and joining it with the original, and, if so, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can generate all dates you need witout creating a table.

If you need all dates from 1.1.2013 till today you can use following query:

```
select (SYSDATE - level) d1 from dual connect by level < (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') - DATE '2013-01-01')
```

and then  join it with you table using an outer join

```
SELECT all_days.d1, SUM(CASE when table.date is null then 0 else 1 end)
FROM 
  ( select (SYSDATE - level) d1 
    from dual 
    connect by level < (TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') - DATE '2013-01-01') 
  ) all_days
  left outer join table on table.DATE = all_days.d1

GROUP BY all_days.d1
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: @mafodope: i've edit my answer.  count(*) include all records. we must count only the records from table (table.date is not null). thats why use SUM instead of count

Comment: I fixed that on my end, thanks. Is it possible to replace DATE '2013-01-01' with e.g. SELECT MIN(table.date) FROM table or something like that?